# How can i receive a reference to a control in WPF (MVVM)?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, reference

In my WPF MVVM Project I have a button that triggers a function that should add a node to a xml and then set the focus to a textbox.
My question is, how can i receive a reference to a control?

View:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=ButtonAddCategory_Click}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
RelayCommand buttonAddCategory_Click;
public ICommand ButtonAddCategory_Click
{
    get
    {
        return buttonAddCategory_Click ?? (buttonAddCategory_Click = new RelayCommand(param => this.AddCategory(),
                                                                                      param => true));
    }
}

public void AddCategory()
{
    ...
    //get the "node" -> reference?
    XmlNode selectedItem = (XmlNode)treeView.SelectedItem;
    ..
    //add the node to the xml
    ..
    //change focus -> reference?
    textBoxTitel.Focus();
    textBoxTitel.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: TreeViews don't play nice with MVVM, unfortunately...

Comment: @Will, actually they *can* play nicely with MVVM, but it requires a bit of work... I use an attached behavior that makes it relatively easy to bind the SelectedItem. See also [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) by Josh Smith

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: lurl, making me do a bit of work to get the same abilities other controls come with out of the box doesn't strike me as playing nice.

Comment: @Will, it's a reusable solution, you only need to do it once...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: in every product you have with a treeview.  Blech.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't do it in the ViewModel.** The ViewModel shouldn't know *anything* about the view.

You can do it in code-behind:

- handle the `TreeView.SelectedItemChanged` event in code-behind, and update a `SelectedItem` property on the ViewModel (you could also do it with an attached behavior)
- to focus the `TextBox`, raise an event from the ViewModel and handle it in code-behind:

**ViewModel:**

```
public XmlNode SelectedItem { get; set; }

public event EventHandler FocusTitle;

public void AddCategory()
{
    ...
    //get the "node" -> reference?
    XmlNode selectedItem = this.SelectedItem;
    ..
    //add the node to the xml
    ..
    // Notify the view to focus the TextBox
    if (FocusTitle != null)
        FocusTitle(this, EventArgs.Empty);

}
```

**Code-behind:**

```
// ctor
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContextChanged += MyView_DataContextChanged;
}

private void MyView_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyViewModel vm = (MyViewModel)e.NewValue;
    vm.FocusTitle += ViewModel_FocusTitle;
}

private void TreeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<Object> e)
{
    MyViewModel vm = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
    vm.SelectedItem = (XmlNode)e.NewValue;
}

private void ViewModel_FocusTitle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxTitle.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`FocusManager.FocusedElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.focusedelement.aspx) attached property to handle ensuring the `TextBox` receives focus.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourViewModel}">
    <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=userInput}">
       <TextBox x:Name="userInput" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

As for your second part (`textBox.SelectAll()`) you may have to work on a behavior or attached property of your own that handles the focusing and selecting in one fell swoop.