# What is the best way to handel click-events in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, relaycommand, attachedbehaviors

What is the best way to handel click-events in MVVM? Are there a best way?

I have found two solutions:

with a relaycommand:

```
RelayCommand buttonAddCategory_Click;
public ICommand ButtonAddCategory_Click
{
    get
    {
        return buttonAddCategory_Click ?? (buttonAddCategory_Click = new RelayCommand(param => this.AddCategory(),
                                                                                      param => true));
    }
}
```

pro: ?; contra: need workaround with events if i would change ui elements [like focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595949/how-can-i-receive-a-reference-to-a-control-in-wpf-mvvm)

with attached behaviour:

```
public static bool GetIsResetMouseLeftButtonDown(TreeView treeView)
{
    return (bool)treeView.GetValue(IsResetMouseLeftButtonDownProperty);
}
public static void SetIsResetMouseLeftButtonDown(TreeView treeViewItem, bool value)
{
    treeViewItem.SetValue(IsResetMouseLeftButtonDownProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsResetMouseLeftButtonDownProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown", typeof(bool), typeof(TreeViewBehavior),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsMouseLeftButtonDownChanged));
```

pro: you have RoutedEventArgs for changes on the ui; contra: access to other controls?

Right now i use both solutions. The RellayCommand in Buttons (with events for ui updates) and the attached behaviour for a treeview to deselect the treeviewitem if a user clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me there is no simple answer to this question.
That's the way I see it:

- if you have a defined state-change on the VM, expose a RelayCommand which then can be bound to something the triggers it. In 99,9% percent of the cases this is a button/menu-entry. Something where it can be easily used. The cases that are left -> well some workaround might be needed, like calling a method from the view.
  So a RelayCommand should imho be used if you are really targeting the VM.
- Focus-changes on the other hand are view-related functionality. Imho this has nothing todo with the WM. That means for me it should be implemented in the view. So to me I'd even go for a straight-forward eventhandler that does the job.

hth,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea:

UI logic, such as opening new windows, showing/hiding elements, etc. You keep that on the code-behind.

When this 'click' should do something with the model, invoke the action.

So, a button that closes the window and saves something would be defined like this:

```
<Button  Name="SaveBtnr" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        Command="{Binding Save}" Click="OnSaveClick"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">Save</Button>
```

And the handler would be:

```
private void OnSaveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do UI Stuff
    }
```

And then your command:

```
  public void SaveCommand(object parameter)
    {
        //SaveStuff            
    }
```